# How does Google Map API authenticate users?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api

They put a limit on the amount of map views, geocodes etc that can be done each day but in the documentation I can't find anywhere where they actually list how it is authenticated.

My guess is it has to be one of the following:

- Website url
- Ip address
- Google account

If anyone knows, that would be really useful.

Comment: v2 was api-key - v3 is IP address https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, there are various way Google is identifying the requests that are done, and most of the time the way it is done is related to your use case.

**For general use and using the 'free' version:** 
You can track the usage by specifying an API key even if it's not necessary anymore.
The requests are managed by URL (referer) and by IP address.

**For general use but with needs to buy additionnal quota:**
You need to use an API key to track the use and you might want to declare URI using the dedicated portal (called console), see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

**For Business users:** 
You will need to include the key inside the script reference to the control, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside#Accessing

Also, here is a summary view of what should be used depending on the type of service you're using as an Enterprise customers: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem